# Odoo how to get current action and menu_id

Tags: url, action, odoo

I want to get action and menu_id in this url

http:// localhost: 8069/web &debug=#id=1&view_type=form&model=res.partner.task&menu_id=126&action=162

I get active_id and active_model but dont get action and menu_id

please help me :((

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help you:

```
from openerp.http import request
# you can find here: Request, OpenERPSession, id of action and other parameters
print(request.__dict__)
```

Comment: Still cannot get `action` & `menu_id` of the current window.. still gave you an up-vote as it was useful'ish, if you know do comment back.

Comment: @maharshi thanks. I do not remember the version of Odoo(on which I tried). But I remember that if you know `id` of action you can find many helpful things. Sorry but I have worked with Odoo 2 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

```
from openerp import http
from openerp.http import request
result = ''
menu = self.env['ir.model.data'].get_object_reference('MODULE NAME', 'MENU ID')
result += request.httprequest.environ['HTTP_REFERER']
result += '#id=' + str(self.id) + '&view_type=form&model=' + request.params["model"] + '&menu_id=' + str(menu[1]) + '&action=' + str(request.params['kwargs']['context']['params']['action'])
return result
```

Comment: kwargs key does not exist